# Unable to upload maxmind binary db to azure storage

Tags: powershell-3.0, azure-blob-storage, maxmind

Is there any rule as to the types of files which can be uploaded on azure blob storage?

I tried uploading the Maxmind binary database, but nothing seems to happen when I try uploading using AZcopy, it does not even go back to prompt but stays after he first line.. 0 files finished..

When trying to upload using Azure Storage Explorer, it throws an error after some time stating the command has been cancelled

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Update: When I tried using powershell, it gave an error 'The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout'.

So I added a timeout of 1 hr and this in turn threw an error stating..
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. HTTP Status Code: 400 - HTTP
Error Message: The specified blob or block content is invalid.

The code I used to upload:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "eventenrichhelpers" -File ".\GeoLite2-City.mmdb" -Blob "GeoLite2-City.mmdb" -ClientTimeoutPerRequest 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no file type restriction. There is however a file size restriction. For Block Blobs, the file size should be <=200GB. When using AzCopy or Set-AzureStorageBlobContent, if no blob type is specified, it will upload your file as a Block Blob by default. And if file is larger than 200GB, upload will fail.

If your file is larger than 200GB, you can upload it as a Page Blob. A Page Blob file size can be <=1TB. To specify the blob type as page blob use the BlobType parameter in AzCopy or Set-AzureStorageBlobContent and specify the value as Page.

Comment: Its a 30MB file, GeoLite2-City.mmdb in http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz , could you please have a look, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second upload with another timeout using the powershell fails for another reason.

If you have an invalid block, replace it with an valid and finally remove it.

```
# create temp dummy file
$tempFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
"delete me" >> $tempFileName
$tempFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFileName

# overwrite blob with dummy file
$tempFile | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $containerName `
    -Blob $blobName `
    -Context $storageContext `
    -Force

# remove dummy blob
Remove-AzureStorageBlob `
    -Container $containerName `
    -Blob $blobName `
    -Context $storageContext `
    -Force
```

That allows you to retry the upload. But i don't know why the upload is so slow that it runs into timeout. I've got that behavior with an file of 50MB.